# Changing logo.svg file on Jekyll GitHub (reducing pixel size does not appear to make change)

Tags: github, svg, jekyll, graphical-logo

I am recently familiarizing myself with templates using Jekyll on GitHub. I have so far been successful for everything - except one item. It is a spaceship-like logo in the top-left corner of each page. An example is [here](https://testmdrs.github.io/elements/).

A different logo was originally in place and I managed to change it to the spaceship-like logo by changing the files in:

1) https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/tree/master/assets/logos
2) https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/tree/master/_site/assets/logos

I *believe* the logo in the top-left corner of the pages is coming from the "logo.svg" file in one of the two directories above. It may be that I am not used to working with .svg files, but I was unable to determine its pixel dimensions and resize its pixel dimensions on my Mac. Instead, I used an online program to reduce the pixel sizes. But even if I do so and push the changes to the GitHub repository, the logo in the top-left corner appears the same size.

Any advice on how to determine the source of the logo and reduce its size would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the displayed logo can be adjusted by changing *max-height* attribute in the

> _sass/_theme.scss

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  max-height: 4rem;
  @include flexbox;
  @include align-items(center);
  img {
    max-height: 5rem;
  }
}
```

When max-height is changed, the width will follow automatically to keep the w/h ratio.